# Re-installing broken Clang++ on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, osx-mountain-lion, clang++

I tried to upgrade to LLVM 3.4 (building from source) and now Clang++ is broken. It cannot find the C++ header files. There also appears to be a problem with missing C header files. For instance it says `fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found`. If I add a manual include for C++ headers in the flags it then complains about not finding string.h.

Clang++ apparently searches these paths:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang++ -cc1 -v
clang -cc1 version 5.0 based upon LLVM 3.3svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/clang/5.0/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

But it doesn't seem to include /usr/include because /usr/include contains string.h. It seems that a reinstallation is best, but when I tried to install the Xcode command line tools from the mpkg file I downloaded, it still doesn't work. Do I have to delete the existing LLVM/Clang first? The only thing that changed is that I can no longer use clang++ as a command on it's own which I think has something to do with macports because in desperation I tried the macports version which also fails (same reason):

```
$ which clang++
/usr/bin/clang++
$ clang++ -cc1 -v
-bash: /opt/local/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
```

I'm using OSX 10.8.4. How can I reinstall or fix this issue?

EDIT: Tried to reinstall LLVM/Clang and I got this:

```
We detected a missing feature in the standard C++ library that was known to be
missing in libstdc++4.6 and implemented in libstdc++4.7. There are numerous
C++11 problems with 4.6's library, and we don't support GCCs or libstdc++ older
than 4.7. You will need to update your system and ensure Clang uses the newer
standard library.
```

Comment: I think I'll try rebuilding LLVM/Clang from source again, though this is what broke it in the first place, so I doubt this will work.

Comment: Trying using configuration option `--enable-libcpp=yes`...

Comment: For others reference do not change things in/usr except /usr/local so you do not affect Apple supplied code. In this case why not reinstall Xcode - or the command line tools - what was the actual error

Comment: I tried reinstalling the command line tools, but that failed. I might try reinstalling Xcode later if building LLVM/Clang from source fails again. Also I did not install anything directly in usr by my own choice. I usually just go with the default install locations.

Comment: And I mentioned the problem above, it's a problem with the header files.

Comment: Rebuilding LLVM was a complete waste of time. Reinstalling Xcode seems to be necessary. >:-(

Answer (score 1):

**Clang isn't broken!**

The program specified a `isysroot` which did not exist and clang would not fail, only give a warning. For those that do not know, this option to clang completely changes the search paths for everything! If clang does not seem to be able to find head files, frameworks, libraries or anything else, checking the `isysroot` is a good place to start.

I manually edited the MakeFile to give a correct `isysroot`. This program uses qmake, so maybe Qt is to blame, or perhaps macports which I installed Qt from. I don't know. But what I do know is that changing the MakeFile solved it.

Hours of headache over one compiler option!